# How to access a container set up in a host with another machine?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have deployed a mosquitto broker with kubernetes in my Linux machine. Now I want to connect this container with a MQTT client running on my smartphone. How could I do that? Which IP should I connect to?

I have connected to the mosquitto broker with a client inside my machine and it works perfectly.

EDIT: I'm using NodePort:

```
NAMESPACE            NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default              service/mosquitto-entrypoint        NodePort    10.152.183.235   <none>        8080:30001/TCP           24h
```

Comment: Is your smartphone somehow aware of your linux machine? Are they on the same network, or you want to expose it to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

If your mobile app is on the same network, ideally NodePort must do good. You must be able to reach your service with IP `10.152.183.235`. 
 But this might not be the scenario I believe

- You must run your service with LoadBalancer type, that will generate an External Facing IP for your cluster. An example given below,

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: example
  ports:
    - port: 8765
      targetPort: 9376
  type: LoadBalancer`

Define a yml for your service, and apply it via kubectl `kubectl apply -f <yourfile>`

If you have a DNS server of your own, then you can prefer using an Ingress Controller and expose your service to outside network.

Comment: `LoadBalancer` mostly depends on Kubernetes running on a cloud provider that can create the load balancer for you.  It's not obvious from the question that the asker is in such an environment.

Comment: Yes. you are right. The LoadBalancer option with Kubernetes exposes your cluster IP to a public IP for accessing it. A NodePort is always fine as long as you are on same network where the cluster is running.

Answer (score 0):

If the host where your service runs is accessible from your smartphone, you could port map the service to Nodeport.

For example , if your machine IP is 192.168.x.y and you map your service to Hosts port/Nodeport 5000

And machine allows incoming connections from your phone when you are connected to allowed network.

You could reach the service on 192.168.x.y:5000